# Manage categories page does not exist in my admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, admin

**I am unable to access my manage categories option in my Magento admin panel.**
When I click on the **manage categories**,**it shows that the page does not exist.**

It redirects to my old website URL of 404 not found page.

I copied the new adminhtml of Magento in it, but still, this error is showing up.
When I open a product, here when I open manage products, then go to edit of product, after the product page is opened. On the product page, There is a categories option tab, here all categories are displaying.

I searched on google but didn't get any specific answer to this problem.  Should I have to make any change in the database to view the manage categories page properly?

Comment: Check error logs there is an error

Answer (score 0):

you should reindex the admin configuration this might help you

you can also get help from bellow link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523668/magento-category-link-to-404-error

check category.phtml

Use the catalog/category helper to get the proper URL from a category model

```
$_catalogCatgoryHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
```

Then with that helper pass your category to the getCategoryUrl() function

```
$_catalogCatgoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category);
```

please check link for detail.

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: thanks, but solution did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Please check for reference on your **error log files**. 
It is located at the **var/log** folder. Check both the exception.log and system.log, you can also paste any error you found here.